# Require packages that are not installed when knitting in R markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

So, I want to knit many .Rmd files into a pdf format. I write the following code:

```
files <- list.files(pattern = "[.]Rmd$")
for (f in files) rmarkdown::render(f, output_format = "pdf_document")
```

However, the process stops continuously as there are many packages that I do not have installed and then I have to install them manually. the following message appears, e.g.:

```
Quitting from lines 33-35 (02-PreProcessing.Rmd) 
Error in library(earth): there is no package called 'earth'
```

What should I add to the code so that the packages are downloaded automatically and I do not have to do so manually?
thanks

Comment: Try `install.packages('earth')` If you want to automatically check and download then use `require(earth)` instead of `library(earth)`

Comment: well, that would be to download it manually. There are other packages that will appear later, and I want to download all these automatically. I do not know what packages are needed to be installed

Comment: If you use an IDE like `Rstudio`, it will automatically suggest to install those packages when it finds the `library` is not installed

Comment: I use Rstudion but it does not suggest to install packaged. It throws an error as I already wrote

Comment: I am not sure about the version of Rstudio you have, but in my experience, it does suggest and install packages if there are some missing

Comment: Rstudio Version 1.4.1103. I am not really sure. I am trying to knit the Rmd files here https://github.com/topepo/caret/tree/master/bookdown

Comment: can you change your `library` to `require` and then run it

Comment: I might do it for the package ```earth```, but what about other packages that will appear whom I do not know and thus cannot ```require``` to be installed?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the best way is to read the files and regex library/require/p_load usage.

sth like that although not tested so small adjustment might be needed:

```
library(magrittr)

files <- list.files(pattern = "[.]Rmd$")

installed_paks <- installed.packages()[, 1]

for (f in files) {
tt <- readLines(f)
# some regex 
rr = "(?:library|require|p_load)\\(\"?\'?([a-zA-Z0-9_\\.]*)\'?\"?\\)"
ll = stringr::str_match_all(tt, rr) %>% do.call(rbind, .))

if (nrow(ll) >0) {
for(pak in ll[ ,2]){
if(! pak %in% installed_paks) install.packages(pak)
}
}
rmarkdown::render(f, output_format = "pdf_document")
}
```

Raw library regex:

```
> (stringr::str_match_all(c("dd", "ddd", "library(miceFast)", "library(aa);library('dd')"), "(?:library|require|p_load)\\(\"?\'?([a-zA-Z0-9_\\.]*)\'?\"?\\)") %>% do.call(rbind, .))[, 2]
[1] "miceFast" "aa"       "dd"
```